# Why are non-ASCII charcters like chinese and danish getting mangled in Tomcat 8 Url Rewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting, tomcat8

I am migrating URL rewrite functionality from Apache mod_rewrite to Tomcat 8's RewriteValve. There are certain rules like

> RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)$ /xyz.do?param=$1 [L]

The rewritten URLs are not working for chinese and other such non-ASCII characters. Checking the rewrite logs, I found that the URL rewrite is working fine. In access logs, the non-ASCII characters are printed as question mark characters. But these URLs were working fine with Apache's mod_rewrite.

The actual URL is [http://www.example.com/abc/在线测试](http://www.example.com/abc/%E5%9C%A8%E7%BA%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95)

**Rewrite Log**

> Rewrote /abc/在线测试 as /xyz.do?param=在线测试 with rule pattern ^/abc/(.*)$

**access log**

> /xyz.do?param=????

**EDIT**

Debugging further I found this behaviour only for querystrings. I am using Tomcat 8.0.35.

**rewrite.config file**

> RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)$ /xyz?$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)/(. *)$ /test/$1?$2 [L]

I added a **Custom logging valve**

```
public class CustomValve extends ValveBase {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomValve.class.getName());

public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
         HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = request.getRequest();
         String contextPath = request.getRequestURI();
         logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Context Path: "+contextPath);
         String queryString = request.getQueryString();
         if(queryString != null)
         {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "QueryString: "+request.getQueryString());
         }
         else 
         {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "QueryString: Null");
         }
         getNext().invoke(request, response);
   }
 }
```

This logging valve was configured with the Rewrite Valve

**context.xml**

```
<Context> 
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
     <Valve className="com.logging.valves.CustomValve"/>
</Context>
```

**URL accessed**

[http://localhost:8080/test/在线测试/在线测试](http://localhost:8080/test/%E5%9C%A8%E7%BA%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95/%E5%9C%A8%E7%BA%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95)

**Custom logger logged**

Context Path: /test/%E5%9C%A8%E7%BA%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95
QueryString: 在线测试

**access log**

/test/%E5%9C%A8%E7%BA%BF%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95?????

The non-ASCII characters in the request URI is encoded but the querystring remains unencoded. Checking the implementation of Tomcat's RewriteValve I found that the request URI is encoded.

```
request.getCoyoteRequest().requestURI().setString(null);
CharChunk chunk = request.getCoyoteRequest().requestURI().getCharChunk();
chunk.recycle();
if (this.context) {
    chunk.append(contextPath);
}
//encoding of request URI
chunk.append(URLEncoder.DEFAULT.encode(urlString));
request.getCoyoteRequest().requestURI().toChars();
```

But no such encoding happens for the querystring

```
if (queryString != null) {
        request.getCoyoteRequest().queryString().setString(null);
        chunk = request.getCoyoteRequest().queryString().getCharChunk();
        chunk.recycle();
        chunk.append(queryString);
        request.getCoyoteRequest().queryString().toChars();
}
```

Is there a way to get around this behaviour?

Comment: Does Tomcat have something similar to the [`B` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) mod_rewrite offers? If so, I’d try with that first.

Comment: No, tomcat does not provide an equivalent to B flag in mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bug 60013](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60013)

Seems to be a bug in the RewriteValve implementation.